# how can i reference an ID from js to html

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, append

```
    <table style="width:100%" id="ex-table">
        <tr id="tr">
            <th>Age:</th>
            <th>first_name:</th>
            <th>last_name:</th>
            <th>notes:</th>
    </table>
```

```
var database = firebase.database().ref().child('users');
database.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        var content = '';
        snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
            var val = data.val();
            content += '<tr>';
            content += '<td>' + val.age + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.first_name + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.last_name + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.notes + '</td>';
            content += '</tr>';
        });
        $("#ex-table").append('content'); //isnt working, 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'
    }
});
```

So Im trying to append the following table in my JS, and for some reason it isnt working. In the console im getting 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'. Anyone know why this is? Its probably something really simple but I just cant figure it out.

Comment: The `$` symbol is usually for jQuery, so your page probably is not importing the library.

Comment: just replace the `$("#ex-table")` with `document.getElementById("ex-table")`

Comment: @TilmanB.akaNerdyyy well that won't entirely work; the subsequent `.append()` call would also have to be modified.

Comment: `content` shouldn't be in quotes./

Comment: You're missing `</tr>` in the initial table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var table = document.getElementById("ex-table");
table.innerHTML += content;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! Although now, when I add data to my database, the same data appears again with the newly added data, so its showing duplicates. How can I make it so it only shows what has been added.

Comment: just set the value of variable table to blank after adding data to database `table.innerHTML = ' '; `

Answer (score 0):

`$("#ex-table")` is jQuery syntax, but you don't have this libary loaded. Use `document.getElementById()`. And then append to its `innerHTML` property.

```
document.getElementById("ex-table").innerHTML += content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use jQuery like this:

```
$(function() {
   // bla bla bla

       $("#ex-table").append(content);
});
```